# Why do I get a runtime error when assigning value to a char pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to change the contents of the char pointer after allocating dynamic memory, is it possible? If not, why? My program throws a run-time error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * str = (char *) malloc (10 * sizeof(char));
    str = "Hello";
    str[2] = 'L'; // here the program throws run time error
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag C++?

Comment: `str = "Hello";` --> `strcpy(str, "Hello");` (`#include <string.h>`)

Comment: @StoryTeller isn't this a valid C++ code

Comment: `str = "Hello";` overwrites the original allocation with a pointer to the charater literal. You cannot write there, hence the error. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @CIsForCookies - So? The tags are for pinpointing a language reference, not increasing exposure for the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)

Comment: No , @LethalProgrammer this particular case is not answered in the question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s , you can check.

Comment: Note that you should *not* cast the result of `malloc()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When pointing `str = "Hello";` you didn't copy the `"Hello"` into the address pointed by `str`. Instead, you pointed `str` to string literal, and modifying it is UB -> run-time-error.

If you want to copy the content of a string `Hello` to `str` use `strcpy`.

*As noted by @LethalProgrammer: using `char[10]` instead of `char*`would allow you modifying the content*

Comment: Surely, @WeatherVane